# envoy configuration has some error after upgrade envoy version

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I have been using envoy as a sidecar on my kubernetes, the version is envoyproxy/envoy:v1.9.1. Recently i tried to upgrade to latest version. However i found out that since v1.17.2, my configuration has some error which i don't have a clue. So appreciate the help. Here is my configuration:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8500
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              config:
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route_dnn_service
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: dnn_service
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.router
                    config: {}
  clusters:
    - name: dnn_service.svc.cluster.local
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      drain_connections_on_host_removal: true
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: dnn_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  health_check_config:
                    port_value: 8501
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: dnn_service.svc.cluster.local
                      port_value: 8500
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8090
```

And the error is following:

Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.listeners[0].filter_chains[0].filters[0]) config: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields

I don't know the error in my configuration file. So please take a look.